# Fabric v2.0 in kubernetes (minikube) - problem running docker inside peer for running chaincode

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to run the Fabric 2.0 test-network in Kubernetes (locally, in minikube) and am facing an issue with the installing or running of the chaincode by the peers (in a docker container, it seems).

I created kubernetes files based on the docker-compose-test-net.yaml and successfully deployed the network, generated the crypto material, created and joined the channel, installed the chaincode on the peers, commited its definition. But when I try to invoke it, I have the following error:

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation:
failed to execute transaction 68e996b0d17c210af9837a78c0480bc7ba0c7c0f84eec7da359a47cd1f5c704a:
could not launch chaincode fabcar_01:bb76beb676a23a9be9eb377a452baa4b756cb1dc3a27acf02ecb265e1a7fd3df:
chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0"
```

I included in that pastebin the logs of the peer. We can see in there that it starts the container, but then I don't understand what happens with it: https://pastebin.com/yrMwG8Nd

---

I then tried as explained here: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/issues/27. Where they say that

> IKS v1.11 and onwards now use containerd as its container runtime
>   instead of the docker engine therefore using docker.sock is no longer
>   possible.

And they propose to deploy a docker pod (dind) with [that file](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/blob/master/configFiles/docker.yaml) and [that file](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/blob/master/configFiles/docker-volume.yaml) and change the occurences of unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock to tcp://docker:2375.

But then I have the following error when I try to install the chaincode:

```
Error: chaincode install failed with status:
500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode':
could not build chaincode:
docker build failed:
docker image inspection failed:
cannot connect to Docker endpoint
```

So it seems it cannot connect to the Docker endpoint. But I cannot find how to fix this.

If you have an idea, it would help a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my issue:

For the peers, I was setting:

```
- name: CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS
  value: peer0-org1-example-com:7052
- name: CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS
  value: 0.0.0.0:7052
```

like they do for the test-network with docker-compose.

Removing those made it work. I guess there were important for the docker-compose setup, but not adequate for kubernetes.

Comment: On top of your suggestion, to fix my issue, I added `CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT="true"` attribute key value to my peer configuration.